# How to get list of all constraints present in a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named STUDENT with following attributes:

```
enroll VARCHAR(20), 
name VARCHAR(50), 
age INT, 
fees FLOAT(6,2)
```

Now I want to know that which all constraints (like Primary Key, Unique Key, NOT NULL, etc) are present in this table. Kindly let me know how can I get this?

Comment: I am looking for some query like 'SHOW INDEX FROM student
' which gives details of table in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JOIN on two tables **USER_CONSTRAINTS** and **USER_CONS_COLUMNS**  to fetch the Column Name, Constraint Type and Table Name.

```
SELECT ucc.COLUMN_NAME, uc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE ,uc.TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS uc  JOIN  USER_CONS_COLUMNS ucc 
ON uc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ucc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
AND uc.TABLE_NAME=ucc.TABLE_NAME
WHERE uc.TABLE_NAME='mytablename';
```

Constraint Definition can be referred as:

```
C (check constraint on a table)
P (primary key)
U (unique key)
R (referential integrity)
V (with check option, on a view)
O (with read only, on a view)
```

For more information you can view Oracle Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1044.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from `user_constraints`

```
SELECT *
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'STUDENT'
```

Make sure you pass the `STUDENT` in caps. table_name is case sensitive

To know the constraint type check this column `CONSTRAINT_TYPE`

Type of constraint definition:

```
C (check constraint on a table)
P (primary key)
U (unique key)
R (referential integrity)
V (with check option, on a view)
O (with read only, on a view)
```

Comment: Hi Prdp, Thanks for your reply.. please can you explain me that what is user_constraints. Is is a keyword?
This code is not working or I am unable to use it properly.

Comment: @rohit - Looks like it shows constraint definitions on tables owned by the current user.

Comment: @rohit - Also sure you pass the STUDENT in caps. table_name is case sensitive

Comment: Hi Prdp, Thanks it worked and showing lots of details. But still I am unable to get the details of Primary Key, Unique Keys etc through this. I am looking for some query like 'SHOW INDEX FROM STUDENT' query used in MySQL which clearly gives the details of all the constraints present in various columns.

Comment: @rohit - It will give the information of below constraints  `(check constraint on a table)
,(primary key)
,(unique key)
,(referential integrity)`. Make sure you table you pass has these constraint

Comment: Hi Prdp, I am getting this result... http://ingenius.in/sql.jpg ...but I am unable to find constraints like Primary Key, NOT NULL, etc which are already present in this table

Answer (score 0):

Try this View query and specify your Table name to get all the constrains detail.

`SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
  WHERE table_name = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>';`

Or

`SELECT * 
  FROM user_constraints
  WHERE table_name = '<your table name>'
  AND constraint_name = '<your constraint name>';`

Comment: Hi AshwinP, Thanks for your reply. In both the ways it is showing "NO ROWS SELECTED"

Comment: Did you put table and constraint names in upper case?

Comment: Yes try with Upper Case

Comment: Hi, I tried this. Kindly check the screenshot and let me know that where I am making mistake... http://ingenius.in/sql2.jpg

Comment: I have tested at my end its show me alll details, can you check one more thing, are you using default schema of oracle or another?

Comment: Hi AshwinP.. please share the screenshot of the output screen which you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

just use `describe`

`describe student`
but remember you should use Web browser mode for it

Comment: Hi Kartik, Thanks for your reply but it is showing only NULL constraint. Kindly let me know that how to use it to get the details of other constraints like UNIQUE KEY, PRIMARY KEY, etc

Comment: Hi Rohit, as i mentioned If you are using SQL command Line from `describe` you can only see NULL constraints but in case of Web Browser mode you can see all of your constraints using `describe`

Comment: Hi Goldy, Thank for your reply. But I need the same to be done in command prompt. Kindly assist me in this.